# Why my click event is happening only once?

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a list element which is holding dropdown-menu drop up bootstrap div.
On click ( markAllMessagesAsSeenHandle() method ) by default on this list element the drop up is showed ,but except that i want to have a click event on my list element. After the initial loading of the page when i click on the list element for thi first time then the click event is happening. But after that when i click again i see nothing printed in the console and the markAllMessagesAsSeenHandler. Why is that ?

```
<div class="wrapper">
<li class="nav-item dropdown" (click)="markAllMessagesAsSeenHandler()">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <svg role="img" class="dropdown-image">
      <image width="24" height="24" xlink:href="assets/img/notification.svg" />
    </svg>
    <div class="notification-icon">
      <span class="" [ngClass]= "(userService.user.unseen_notifications_no != 0) ? 'notification-icon__number-positive' : 'notification-icon__number-negative'">{{ userService.user.unseen_notifications_no }}</span>
    </div>
    <span class="up-icon">&#8963;</span>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropup" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let message of messages">
      <div class="notification">
        <div class="notification__message"> {{ message.notification }} </div>
        <div class="notification__details">
         <button class="notification__details-info redirect-button" (click)="redirectTo(message)">Action</button>
         <p class="notification__details-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" [title]="message.created_at | date:'medium'">{{ moment(message.created_at).fromNow() }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div *ngIf="messages && messages.length == 0" class="zero-notifications">You don't have any notifications</div>
    <button *ngIf="messages && messages.length != 0" class="dropdown-menu__get-more primary" (click)="getMoreNotificationsHandler()">Get More</button>
  </div>
</li>
</div>
```

```
// Method
markAllMessagesAsSeenHandler() {
console.log("test");
}
```

Comment: You have tagged jquery and angular.  Are you using it with angular? If its manipulating the dom Angular wont know, and thats possibly causing your issue.

Comment: Like @cjd82187 said, there might be DOM manipulations that are not visible to Angular. You are using Bootstrap, most of the features in Bootstrap that involve jQuery and/or JS in Bootstrap are not very compatible with Angular because Angular does not keep track of these operations done by Bootstrap.